# Sub branch projects are not displaying in TFS Server

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

TFS sub branch projects are not displaying in TFS Server, but in our organization, some of the users can view the branch projects. Only a few users can not view the sub branch projects in all root solution. it will happens all the solution in a server.

Please give me what the permission need to change. and what are the changes need to do. Please find the screenshot.

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1XcokKgwDvSFljeDNRBHhgua3CNUgUtQL

Comment: Do you mean some of the users can't see team projects? (what is sub branch projects?)

Comment: Yes,Team projects